# How to access parent form from the child form?

Tags: c#, forms

I've tried looking this up and I couldn't find anything that I understood.

But what I'm trying to do is create a class with all my functions in, then call it from the parent form.

And one of these functions contains adding controls to the parent form, but I cannot find out how to do this, can somebody help me please and explain it along the way?

Many thanks,
Jarrod

Comment: You should show some code (what you have tried).

Comment: I've tried several ways;

this.Parent.Controls.Add(myButton);

But that came up with an exception, then I tried another way, but that just didn't do anything at all.

Comment: Post what and all you tried and what was the result

Comment: Show us the code so that we can have a look, or explain a little more.

Comment: Pls make it clear how you relate two forms as `parent` and `child` ?

Comment: So my first form is called Form1 (Parent which calls the child class)
And my second form is called KeyboardGenerator (which contains all the classes)

And when my KeyboardGenerator is called, I want it to add controls back to the parent so that users can click on them and interact. I know that I could just miss out the KeyboardGenerator class and insert it as a method into the Form1 but that makes the code untidy

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I'd just add a reference to the parent form in the lower class and initialize it in the constructor. Something like this:

```
public form MyForm : Form
{
    Foo myFoo;

    public MyForm()
    {
        this.myFoo = new Foo(this);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private MyForm parentForm;

    public Foo(MyForm parent)
    {
        parentForm = parent;
    }
}
```

Then you can reference the parent form and manipulate it how you wish. It also works for static classes, too.

Comment: Right idea. but this won't compile `Foo myFoo = new Foo(this)` if it is in `FieldInitializer`

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I'll edit it so that the initializer is in the form's constructor.

Comment: Now looks okay. but not sure this is what OP meant!

Comment: Hmm, how so? OP wants to have methods in his "child" class that add controls to the parent form - I think this should be able to do that, unless I'm missing something with threading issues...

Comment: No, am not saying you're wrong but we're not sure this is what Op meant right?

Comment: Hmm, you may have a point. OP says he tried `this.Parent.Controls.Add`, which produced an exception, but if he had no parent reference, it wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: Whenever I try to add your code, it has a problem with `Public Foo(MyForm parent)`
`Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Simple_Test.UI_Generator.Keyboard.Keyboard(Simple_Test.UI_Generator.Keyboard)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\TailStudios\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Simple Test\Form1.cs 18 26 Simple Test`

And that line is:    `this.myFoo = new UI_Generator.Keyboard(this);`

Comment: There should be another error directly above or below that one in the Error List. Could you post that one, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

In your class use this method to add controls to Parent form

```
public static void AddControl(Form ParentForm,Control control,Point location)
{
control.Location=location;//This is only to show you
Parent.Controls.Add(control);//how it can be done.You can replace this logic with yours
//but make sure to add this Parent.Controls.Add(control),where control will be the name of        your Control.
}
```

Then whenever you need to add a control call the function as;

```
ClassName.AddControl(this,new TextBox(),new Point(10,10));//Change ClassName to your class's name.
```

Anything else please let me know.